# Inline SVG loading via innerHTML but not displaying in mozilla, but only in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, local-storage, mozilla

I have a SVG tag in my HTML code as:

```
<svg height="1094.484" id="svg_elem" version="1.1" width="773.75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs></svg>
```

I do the innerHTML on this SVG element to put in the paths as:

```
var get_data = localStorage.getItem("svg_data");
document.getElementById("svg_elem").innerHTML = get_data ;
```

My local storage consists the paths that are to be put into SVG's innerHTML. However, when I do this the SVG loads the inner HTML correctly as:

```
<svg height="1094.484" id="svg_elem" version="1.1" width="773.75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 3; pointer-events: none; -webkit-user-select: text;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); -webkit-user-select: text;">Created with Raphaël 2.1.2</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); -webkit-user-select: text;"></defs><path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; -webkit-user-select: text;" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M95.53125,172L95.53125,171L160.53125,171" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg>
```

But the path (a straight line) is not displayed on the screen. **It works fine in Chrome,  but does not work in Mozilla**. How can I get this run in Mozilla?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add all your svg-text including `<svg ... </svg>` with innerHTML to a DIV.

Comment: Yeah, that should  work, havent tried it though. Buut that is not something I am looking for. I cannot put closing div tags around this, as SVG tags are created dynamically throug a jquery. Any other solution, please?